# Can bluetooth be used in an application of notifying people when their friends are near them, assuming both have bluetooth enabled devices

Tags: bluetooth, bluetooth-low-energy

I have a project. I want to make people aware that their friends are near them without using any internet. Is bluetooth a better option? Or is there anything better than this?

Comment: Make the phone lock up and display "look around". If there are friends, you will be able to spot them...

Comment: possible duplicate of [Can the range of bluetooth be adjusted?](http://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/172393/can-the-range-of-bluetooth-be-adjusted)

Comment: Yes, but if you are involved in your phone doing some stuff and you are in a crowded place and a friend of yours is in your vicinity, its good if you get a notification stating that your friend **** is here, go and meet him, right? I am asking can Bluetooth be used for such type of application? @PlasmaHH

Comment: google BLE beacon

Comment: @VimalRockstar: If I am going somewhere to meet a friend I will make sure that we find each other without any gadgets.

Comment: That's great. It's how it need to be. But sorry I think you have mistaken my question or comment or I didn't put it in the right way, that may be my mistake, I apologize. The situation actually I am giving here is when you don't know you are at the same place, you both went to the same place accidentally or crossed your way with your friend accidentally. @PlasmaHH

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Bluetooth will certainly work for this, if you're happy with the range and the requirement to "pair" phones before they will communicate. For details of how to do that you should ask the software Stackexchange.

Comment: They wouldn't need to pair. A bluetooth scanner could pop up when it notices a specific bluetooth mac nearby, much like the wifi scanner does.